# Python --command command line option

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to use python -c command line option but cannot seem to make it work.
What is the right way to use it?
Sometime it is really useful to store the whole command and one line and make an alias for it then going into the interactive mode.

The following gives no output

```
-bash-3.2$ python -c "
import hashlib
hashlib.md5('test').hexdigest()"
```

But of course following works

```
-bash-3.2$ python
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5('test').hexdigest()
'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've got to `print` what you want to see if in non-interactive mode.

```
python -c "import hashlib
print hashlib.md5('test').hexdigest()"
```

the interactive mode always prints the return values, but this is just a gimmick of the CLI

Answer (score 2):

```
python -c "import hashlib; print(hashlib.md5('test').hexdigest())"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>python -c "import hashlib; print hashlib.md5('test').hexdigest()"
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

You are missing the `print`, which is why you don't see anything.

Comment: Hi, How can one deal with indentation while running `python -c` command. Suppose I want to run a `try..except` code.